# I want to convert the following mysql query in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

"select * from categories where id NOT IN(select parent_id from categories);" in mongoose. I am new in mongoose. Please suggest something so that i can get the expected result. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose does not support nested queries. You have to use two step to done this:

```js
let parentIds = await Category.find({}, {parent_id: 1});

parentIds = parentIds.map(pid => pid.parent_id);

const categories = await Category.find({_id: {$nin: parentIds}});
```